# Difference between OnClusterClickListener and OnClusterItemClickListener

Tags: android, google-maps, markerclusterer

The docs doesn't say much at all..

> OnClusterItemClickListener - Called when an individual ClusterItem is clicked.
>
> OnClusterClickListener - Called when a Cluster is clicked.

What exactly is the difference between them?

If a cluster is a group of map markers that were grouped into one, how exactly can a single item be clicked if only the cluster is showing on the map?

Comment: `OnClusterItemClickListener` returns a cluster item and `OnClusterClickListener` returns the whole cluster ?

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me which is related to my 2nd question.. a cluster is a group of items together and these items are not shown on the map anymore.. so how can I press an item which is not shown on the map? Only the cluster itself will be shown doesn't it?

Comment: well not really,  if you zoom out a lot, you could have more than one cluster at time

Comment: OK but its still a cluster which contains items. If the cluster contains items and items can not be seen on the map (you see only the cluster itself and not his items), then how can I even press the items?

Comment: are you still asking for the difference between those or for use cases ?

Comment: between them. I might don't understand the more basic definition of the difference between a cluster and a cluster item. From what I understand, a cluster item is a single marker. A cluster is a group of many cluster items. Is that correct?

Comment: I got the answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I understand my confusion now.

When you add markers to the map, they are being added as items and when they are not grouped together and still show as an individual markers, you can click on them, and then the `OnClusterItemClickListener` is called.

When the items are grouped to a single cluster, and you click on it, the `OnClusterClickListener` will be called.

Comment: You figured it out yourself and explained very correctly @Yonatan Nir :)

Comment: @Yonatan Nir Sir I need your Intervention in one of my problem as I am facing one problem regarding google map clustering is there any way we can chat and discuss it down.

Comment: @NikhilSingh I'm not an expert on the subject but you can open a question here in the site and put here a link to the question